# LINQ: Searching inside child entities

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 'Property' objects with 'BayOption' child objects. I need the site search to search through the child BayOptions as well as the Properties and return Properties if the search criteria matches the child or parent. A Property can have multiple BayOptions (and usually does). I was unsure if .Select or .SelectMany is the trick I need. I have the following so far:

```
 var stringResults = db.Properties
                .Where(x => x.Address.Contains(id)... (more conditions here...but then BayOptions)
                || x.BayOptions.Select(g => g.Description).Contains(id)
               );
```

But would the .Select here only select one BayOption? (I don't think so, but .SelectMany makes me wonder...)
At any rate, I am not getting results for the child objects with this as it is.

Comment: You could use `Any`: `|| x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(id))`

Comment: That's not working. "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'bool'..." on 'g.Description'

Comment: I believe .Any returns a bool if there are matches... that's not what I need.

Comment: @Beau:  You're inside a `.Where()`.  bool is what you need.

Comment: but it isn't working... see above: "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'bool'..." on 'g.Description'

Comment: @Beau Could you please show what you currently have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use LINQ `.Any()`:

```
var stringResults = db.Properties.Where(x =>
    x.Address.Contains(id) ||
    /* Other conditions || */
    x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(id)));
```

Here, `x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description.Contains(id))` will return true if any of the `BayOptions` values have a description which contains the ID.

Comment: returning 'true' doesn't seem to help me... am I missing something? I need to return Properties that satisfy the requirement of the child's description matching the id (search term). I tried this, but am getting: "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'bool'..." on 'g.Description'

Comment: @Beau Double-check your parentheses.

Comment: List<Property> stringResults = db.Properties
                    .Where(
                           x=>x.Address.Contains(searchString)
                        || x.BayOptions.Any(g => g.Description).Contains(searchString)
                        ).ToList();   gives me an error on Description cannot convert string to bool

Comment: @Beau You've accidentally placed a parenthesis after `g.Description`. http://i.imgur.com/ErLF4Rt.png

Comment: @Beau You're also missing a closing parenthesis right before `.ToList()`